# Using a boolean vector to extract a subarray of an ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, boolean, slice

I have an ndarray:

```
ndaM = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]);
```

and a vector of 0s and 1s:

```
vSet = [0,1,1];
```

How do I use `vSet` to extract the submatrix with only rows and columns whose index is nonzero in `vSet`? In this case, the matrix

```
[[5,6],[8,9]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with a two-step slicing:

```
# convert vSet to a boolean array
bSet = np.array(vSet).astype(bool)

# slice in two steps, rows first, then columns
ndaM[bSet][:, bSet]

#array([[5, 6],
#       [8, 9]])
```

Or use [np.ix_](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) to create an index mesh grid and then use it for indexing:

```
ndaM[np.ix_(bSet, bSet)]
#array([[5, 6],
#       [8, 9]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that slices in one go using `np.ix_`

```
ndaM[np.ix_(*2*(np.array(vSet, bool),))]
# array([[5, 6],
#        [8, 9]])
```

Or in more readable two lines

```
mask = np.array(vSet, bool)
ndaM[np.ix_(mask, mask)]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `np.ix_` applies `np.nonzero` (`np.where`) to a boolean input to turn it into a numeric index.  `(array([[1], [2]]), array([[1, 2]]))`.
`

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks! I wasn't aware of that.